# Which Jean Giraud book is containing those organic wall Moebius textures?

Tags: comics, illustrated-story

Which Jean Giraud book is containing those organic wall Moebius textures?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two paintings appear to be from his art book [*Quatre-vingt huit*](https://stuartngbooks.com/quatre-vingt-huit-en.html) (1990), if that's what you're asking.

I'm not sure this is on-topic, though, it doesn't seem to have any obvious SF content.

Comment: +1 Looks like sci-fi art? (Like, how H. R, Giger is sci-fi. :)

Comment: @Lexible That's probably fair; to the extent that I can read the French, a number of people seem to compare his work (or at least these ones) to Giger.  I just felt I had to note the reservation in the interest of full disclosure.

Comment: FWIW, Giraud usually used Moebius on his scifi/fantasy works and Jean Giraud on his historical comics. This was published as a Moebius work.